# how to create tuples with below 2 list in given order

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
A=[1,2,3]
B=[4,5,6]

o/p : [(1,6).(2,5),(3,6)]
```

how I can achieve above output . as i have tried using zip but its giving first element of first list with 1st element of second list .

Comment: Did you mean `[(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4)]`? If so, it would be: `zip(A, B[::-1])`.

Comment: yes my output should contain : [(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4)]

Comment: @vikrambhati--then my answer works.

Answer (score 2):

You can zip with the second list [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=reversed#reversed):

```
>>> A=[1,2,3]
>>> B=[4,5,6]
>>> list(zip(A, reversed(B)))
[(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: @vikrambhati: no problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

This won't put them in a `(a, b)` format, but at least they are in the right order.

```
A = [1,2,3] 
B = [4,5,6]
C = [tup for i in range(3) for tup in (A[i], B[- i - 1])]
```

Printing `C` outputs: `[1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4]`.

Comment: `[(A[i], B[- i - 1]) for i in range(3)]` would give you the desired result.

Comment: lol now I feel like I was asking the question. ty!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to create the tuples with a given order.

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [4, 5, 6]
C = [(A[i], value) for i, value in enumerate(B[::-1])]
```

And this yields the values in C

```
[(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4)]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
list(zip(a, reversed(b)))
[(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4)]
keys = ["name", "age"]
values = ["wanglei", 30]
dict(zip(keys, values))
{'name': 'wanglei', 'age': 30}
```

Comment: Your answer is just code? Could you explainit further. Have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to get started with writing awesome answers.